# How to create array inside XML

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core

I need help with creating array inside `XML document`.

I am able to create a file with a single user, but that need to be a list.

I have this as `UserList.cs`

```
    [XmlRoot("MyList")]
    public class MyListXml
    {
        [XmlElement("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("User")]
        public UserXml usersXml { get; set; }

        public class UserXml
        {
            [XmlElement("Id")]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

        }
}
```

and this inside my controller

```
        public void GetUsersXml()
        {
            MyListXml myListXml = new MyListXml
            {
                Id = 5,
                Date = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),

                UsersXml = new UserXml
                {
                    Id = 111,
                    Name = "John Doe",
                }
            };

            userListXml.SaveXml("userList.xml");

        }
```

I am getting XML document with following data

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Id>5</Id>
  <Date>2019-11-04</Date>
  <User>
    <Id>111</Id>
    <Name>John Doe</Name>
  </User>
</MyList>
```

but like I said, I need a `list of users`, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Id>5</Id>
  <Date>2019-11-04</Date>
  <User>
    <Id>111</Id>
    <Name>John Doe</Name>
  </User>
  <User>
    <Id>112</Id>
    <Name>Jane Doe</Name>
  </User>
  <User>
    <Id>113</Id>
    <Name>Bill Doe</Name>
  </User>
</MyList>
```

I know I need to use `foreach` with data from my `database`, but I am not sure where to place a `foreach` nor is my code correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following :

```
    [XmlRoot("MyList")]
    public class MyListXml
    {
        [XmlElement("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("User")]
        public List<UserXml> usersXml { get; set; }

    }
    public class UserXml
    {
        [XmlElement("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: yes, very dumb from me, it needs to be a list, but what about the controller? I need to have two XMLs and then to append a list of users to the first XML?

Comment: Your input is a database with users (could be a file).  So first you create : MyListXml xml = new MyListXml();  Then add the data to the class.  After all the data is in the class then you serialize the class.  The users you add to the property xml.usersXml.Add(new UserXml() { Id = 123, Name = "John"});